# ReactJs: How to handle state objects with properties

Tags: reactjs

I'm playing around with ReactJs and I was wondering if its possible to work with state objects that have properties. Now I made a pseudo code example below which has a simple object, but I would like to handle cases where I have a lot of objects with properties of their own.

E.g. I would like to handle cases such as:

```js
//Initialize object
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        myObject: {
            prop1: "",
            prop2: ""
        }
    };
}

//How I would assign to a property of that object
setProp1: function(event) {
    this.setState({myObject.prop1: event.target.value});
},
```

```html
//Rendering the item (jsx)
<div>
    <div className="custom">{myObject.prop1}</div>
    <span>{myObject.prop2}<span>
</div>
```

Is something like the example above possible? Or do I need to attach each property to the state directly? What would be the best way to handle a scenario like this in Reactjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to create a new object with the specified property changed. You can do this with something like [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (using [shims](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.assign) or [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign) if necessary):

```javascript
var newMyObj = Object.assign({}, this.state.myObject, {
  prop1: event.target.value
});
this.setState({myObject: newMyObj});
```

You could also use the [React immutability helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) to assist with updating nested structures:

```javascript
var newMyObj = update(this.state.myObject, { prop1: { $set: event.target.value } });
this.setState({myObject: newMyObj});
```

If you're using Babel, JSX, or something that supports [ES7 rest/spread property](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) operations, you can simplify the code a bit (this is my favorite option when available because I think it reads better):

```javascript
var newMyObj = {
  ...this.state.myObject,
  prop1: event.target.value
};
this.setState({myObject: newMyObj});
```

You will often see examples that simply update the existing object and re-set the state, but **this is not recommended:**

```javascript
// antipattern!
this.state.myObject.prop1 = event.target.value;
this.setState({myObject: this.state.myObject});
```

Comment: Which option do you recommend and why?

Comment: @scripton I generally prefer the ES7 syntax when in a project that supports it because I think it reads easier and it desugars into `Object.assign` anyway. The React immutability helpers are nice when you're manipulating deeply nested objects and/or arrays and don't have access to the rest/spread operators, but they do essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will check that out as it seems to suit my needs.